# How can I turn the following dataframe into a multi-index dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

How can I achieve the following:
I have a table like so

```
|----------------------|
| Date | A | B | C | D |
|------+---+---+---+---|
| 2000 | 1 | 2 | 5 | 4 |
|------+---+---+---+---|
| 2001 | 2 | 2 | 7 | 4 |
|------+---+---+---+---|
| 2002 | 3 | 1 | 7 | 7 |
|------+---+---+---+---|
| 2003 | 4 | 1 | 5 | 7 |
|----------------------|
```

and turn it into a multi-index type dataframe:

```
|------------------------------------|
| Column Name | Date | Value | C | D |
|-------------+------+-------+---+---|
|      A      | 2000 |   1   | 5 | 4 |
|             |------+-------+---+---|
|             | 2001 |   2   | 7 | 4 |
|             |------+-------+---+---|
|             | 2002 |   3   | 7 | 7 |
|             |------+-------+---+---|
|             | 2003 |   4   | 5 | 7 |
|-------------+------+-------+---+---|
|      B      | 2000 |   2   | 5 | 4 |
|             |------+-------+---+---|
|             | 2001 |   2   | 7 | 4 |
|             |------+-------+---+---|
|             | 2002 |   1   | 7 | 7 |
|             |------+-------+---+---|
|             | 2003 |   1   | 5 | 7 |
|------------------------------------|
```

I have tried using the Melt function on a dataframe but could not figure out how to achieve this desired look. I think I would also then have to apply a groupby function to the melted dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) with [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html). By adding `C` and `D` as `id_vars`, the columns will keep the same structure, then you can just set the columns of interest as index to get a `MultiIndex` dataframe:

```
df.melt(id_vars=['Date', 'C', 'D']).set_index(['variable', 'Date'])

               C  D  value
variable Date             
A        2000  5  4      1
         2001  7  4      2
         2002  7  7      3
         2003  5  7      4
B        2000  5  4      2
         2001  7  4      2
         2002  7  7      1
         2003  5  7      1
```

Comment: If the Date column is actually my index, is there any way to modify the code to account for this?

Comment: Just reset the index, `df.reset_index().melt(id_vars=['Date', 'C', 'D']).set_index(['variable', 'Date'])` @jason